Каким образом можно автоматизировать HTTP запросы на интернет-ресурс, чтобы они выполнялись круглосуточно?
Задача следующая: есть URL, на который требуется с определенной периодичностью отправлять POST-запросы 24/7. Набросал код на JS и запустил на ноде, все работает. Но свой компьютер постоянно включенным держать не могу. Первая идея - арендовать виртуальный сервер и отправлять запросы с него, но в серверной разработке я полный ноль. Арендованный виртуальный сервер у меня есть, но использую я его только для тестов фронтенда, с серверными скриптами ни разу не работал. Есть ли вообще такая возможность? Подскажите направление куда копать.


Можно развернуть NodeJS на сервере и использовать его (если хостер поддерживает данное)
Смог написать на JS - значит сможешь и на php поднять тоже самое.

Ну и финал - засунуть в crontab (в планировщик заданий) исполнение скрипта.

У меня самый урезанный тариф, даже не VPS, а по сути виртуальный веб-хостинг (reg.ru хост с панелью управления ipsmanager). Node JS не этом тарифе не поддерживается, только скрипты php или python. А VPS/VDS поднять я пока вряд ли смогу. Может подскажете какие инструменты php или python для выполнения сетевых запросов? И вообще сам факт того, что один сервер отсылает сетевой запрос на другой сервер это норм? Возможно? Просто по моим небольшим знаниям серверной части всегда было так: "сервер принимает запросы, обрабатывает и генерирует ответ", а вот, чтобы сам выполнял запросы, такого я не видел

@VladislavG. не знаю вашего скрипта и его результата. Но вы можете выполнить с сервера любой нужный вам запрос. С планировщика заданий вообще не проблема. Пишите на php и горя знать не будете. Я понимаю, что и на nodejs можно, но не все хостерпровайдеры поддерживают её работу на своих хостингах. Проблему решает свой сервер VPS/VDS и поднять его нет сложности, а вот обеспечить его безопасность уже нужно приложить определённые усилия и знания. Обратите своё внимание на cURL и file_get_contents в php. cURL имеет расширенную настройку соединения

Нашел решение проще, чем реализация на сервере, и к тому же бесплатное: использовать Yandex Cloud Functions

Это не решение. Это костыль...
Вы используете третью сторону для выполнения задач, которые вы сами же можете сделать.
Однозначно - это не решение.

Если Вы ещё не знакомы с Python, то ознакомьтесь с библиотекой requests - она не является стандартной, поэтому для Python её необходимо будет дополнительно установить через консоль:
pip install requests

С ней можно в цикле с паузами настроить отправку нужного Вам POST-запроса:
import time
import requests

url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
body = {
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "test"
}

while True:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
    print("Status Code ", response.status_code)
    time.sleep(60)  # пауза в секундах

Материалов по библиотеке в интернете очень много, поэтому с тем, как добавить в код нужных Вам опций, проблем не должно возникнуть.
